# How to back up initial state of external backup drive?

Tags: backup, cloning, ntfs

I've picked up an [HP Simplesave](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/manualCategory?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=ca&product=4023094&) external drive.  It comes with some fancy software that is of no use to me because I don't use Windows.  Like many current consumer-targeted backup drives, the backup software is actually contained on the drive itself.  I'd like to save the drive's initial state so that I can restore it if I decide to sell it.

The backup box itself is somewhat customized: in addition to the hard drive device, it presents a CDROM-like device on `/dev/sr0`.   I gather that the purpose of this cdrom device is to bootstrap via Windows autoplay the backup application which lives on the disk itself.  I wouldn't suppose any guarantees about how it does this, so it seems important to preserve the exact state of the disk.

The drive is formatted with a single 500GB NTFS partition.

My initial thought was to use `dd` to dump the disk (`/dev/sdb`) itself, but this proved impractical, as the resulting file was not sparse.  This seemed to be because the NTFS empty space is not filled with zeroes, but with a repeating series of 16 bytes.

I tried gzipping the output of `dd`. This reduced to the file to a manageable size — the first 18GB was compressed to 81MB, versus 47MB to tarball the contents of the mounted filesystem — but it was very slow on my admittedly somewhat derelict Pentium M processor.  The time to do that first 18GB was about 30 minutes.

So I've resorted to dumping the disk state and partition data separately.

- I've dumped the partition state with

  ```
  sfdisk -d /dev/sdb > sfdisk.-d.out
  ```
- I've also created a compressed image of the NTFS partition (the only one on the disk) with

  ```
  ntfsclone --save-image --output - /dev/sdb1 | gzip -c > ntfsclone.img.gz
  ```

Is there anything else I should do to ensure that I can restore the precise original state of the drive?

Comment: [crossposted on superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/227983/how-to-back-up-initial-state-of-external-backup-drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sfdisk -d` dumps the partition table but not the rest of the boot sector, so if there was a bootloader on the disk it won't be restored. You can save the boot sector with `head -c 512 </dev/sdb >bootsector.img`.